# Show status bar a default message

Tags: c++, qt, statusbar

I have created a status bar in Qt. I am developing a webbrowser. When the user hovers a link the status bar shows the link hovered.

That works but how do I set a default text when the status bar is blank?

Is there any option to do this?

Comment: What class are you using for your HTML display widget?  Is it QWebView, or QWebEngineView, or something else?

Comment: please post some code how you created status bar and how you created web view

Comment: Sorry for delay! I downloaded http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkitexamples-webkitwidgets-browser-example.html and I am trying to understand it and to modify it. I am trying so, to add a "placeholder" to the statusbar. It is QWebView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect the `linkHovered` signal of the `QWebPage` to the statusBar, can't you simply check whether it is empty and then display whatever message you like?

The code below seems to do what you describe, but maybe I misunderstood what you were asking? Note: I simply created a `QMainWindow` which has a status bar by default.

```
#ifndef MYMAINWINDOW_H
#define MYMAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow, private Ui::MainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
  MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent), defaultMessage("Default Message")  {
    setupUi(this);
    webView->load(QUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
    this->statusBar()->showMessage(defaultMessage);
    connect(webView->page(),SIGNAL(linkHovered(const QString & , const QString & , const QString & )),
            this, SLOT( hovered(const QString & , const QString & , const QString & ) ) );
  }

  public slots:

  void hovered(const QString & link, const QString & title, const QString & textContent) {
    this->statusBar()->showMessage(link == "" ?  defaultMessage : link);
  }

 private:
  QString defaultMessage;

};

#endif
```

Let me know if this helps.